# What does 'http: getaddrinfo*.gaih_getanswer: got type "46"' mean

Tags: authentication, http, log-files

Today I got an e-mail from logcheck informing me that the following system event occurred.

```
http: getaddrinfo*.gaih_getanswer: got type "46"
```

Indeed, the above message occurs 4 times in `/var/log/auth.log` 
it occurred twice yesterday around 6:46 am. And this morning it also occurred twice around the same time.

I wonder what this message means and if this message is something to worry about or if should just tell logcheck to ignore it.
If it is something to worry about, then any pointers on how to fix the problem are appreciated.

Comment: See https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14841 It's getting confused because it got a DNSSec response as well. (old question, but as I landed here with Google, putting a pointer for the next person).